# DocuSign, User Certificates, and eIDAS

Tags: digital-signature, pki

Based on my understanding in order to by eIDAS compliant, signer's digital certificate is included in the PAdES envelope.
However when i sign a document with DocuSign and open it with Acrobat reader, under the signature panel it shows that document is signed with DocuSign's certificate as per image below.

Q1. Does docusign create a digital certificate per user when they signup?

Q2. does docusign use that certificate for signing? if yes why not shown in image with the chain of trust?

Q3. Is such a document eIDAS compliant or not?

[image]

Comment: You need to ask the place that sent you the Docu Sign. Above is how it works for me.

Comment: above is how it works for me as well. no one sent me the document. the question is where is my digital certificate in this process ?

Comment: If no one sent you a document then there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: Is such a document eIDAS compliant or not?

Answer (score 1):

"eIDAS compliance" is a bit of a vague term. See the text of the [regulation here](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014R0910&from=EN)

Somewhat confusingly it recognizes some form of electronic signatures ("electronic signature" by its definition can also cover scans of a physical signature), but its main effect is that it recognizes qualified electronic signatures (QES) as equivalent to physical signatures in EU, so it's a pretty big deal.

There are several criteria for a QES but the DocuSign one that you linked above is probably not valid or if it is, it's at most an "electronic seal" (i.e. it validates that it's from DocuSign and it's physical equivalent would be a stamp from their front desk). A properly qualified signature would require a signature with a certificate associated with the person that is from one of the trusted CAs (in the European Trusted List), and with the private key held on a qualified physical device (it's a special bit in the certificate).

IANAL, so take all of this with a big grain of salt. I have dealt a lot with validating signatures for EIDAS compliance and the ones I've seen from DocuSign usually fail some of the above tests. If you want to see more detail from a sample [see here](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation)